# Convert date time from UTC to user time zone

Tags: jquery, angular, datetime, timezone

I have to show the date and time according to the user's timezone. I have saved the UTC date-time while insertion into DB. I have tried below code but it is working only in Chrome:

```
let dateTimeConverted = new Date(new Date(jsonObject.calculationDateTime) + '.000Z');
```

I am able to get the current user's timezone offset using below code:

```
var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset();
```

I have tried a few things to convert to user's timezone and show user's timezones' date time, but I wasn't successful might be I am doing something wrong. please help me to figure out this.

Comment: What *exactly* is in `jsonObject.calculationDateTime`?  Is it a string? If so, show an example.  Is it a `Date` object? If so, how was it originally created? From a timestamp or string? Please show it.  Also - what are you *doing* with the result?  Show that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use moment.js

```
let date = new Date().toUTCString();
console.log("UTC Date: " + date); // UTC Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2019 07:50:46 GMT

let localDate = moment(date).local(true).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log("Moment Local Date: " + localDate); // Moment Local Date: 2019-06-27 13:20:46
```

Comment: How i can do it in angular with moment Package?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these solutions, might it can help

1. Use `Moment.js` library

   ```
   let desireDdate = moment(date).local(true).format("requiredformat");
   ```

   for example pass requiredformat  :- `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`
2. Try this with time zone like this :-

   By Default `pipe` convert datetime into local(browser) time zone because internally it is using locale

   `The user date is {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}`

   if date is in this format 2022-05-25T10:25:55 then add **'Z' at end** then use
   date pipe`

   OR:

   There is other way also, just add UTC at the end of Date like this

   ```
    let desireDdate = new Date('25/05/2022 10:25:55 PM UTC');
   ```